# Как сделать в select что-то вроде placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Есть

```
<select name="s">
     <option></option>
</select>
```

В этом `select` несколько значений `option` . И когда `select` еще не развернут, в нем по умолчанию виден первый `option`.

Вопрос: Каким образом сделать чтобы по умолчанию там был мой текст, а когда развернуть этот селект, в нем моего текста уже не было?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Let me Google it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box) (Вопрос заданный тысячу раз, где только можно)
Под линком - оригинальный тред на SO.com

```
<select onclick = 'this.children[0].remove()'>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="hurr">Durr</option>
</select>
//Слегка модифицированный код под нужды спрашивающего. Суть поясняет, все красивости добавляются по вкусу
```

---

UPD: Более "качественная" реализация на голом css+html.

```css
option[default] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="" default disabled selected>Select your option...</option>
  <option value="hurr">Hurr</option>
  <option value="durr">Durr</option>
</select>
```

Comment: второй раз кликнешь, что будет?

Comment: `Вопрос: Каким образом сделать чтобы по умолчанию там был мой текст, а когда развернуть этот селект, в нем моего текста уже не было?`    
`//Суть поясняет, все красивости добавляются по вкусу`
Это отвечает на вопрос? Да, отвечает. Я указал, что это передает суть, дальнейшее развитие кода на усмотрение автора? Да, указал. К чему вопросы?

Comment: к тому что качество ответа хромает. Если уж пишите ответ, то пишите качественно, а не полурабочей вариант. В таком случае лучше бы в комментариях отправили ссылку на оригинал, и все.

Comment: @teran, мне кажется, мой ответ удовлетворяет вопрос автора. Код рабочий на 100%, во всяком случае относительно задачи. Я не думаю, что автор не в состоянии допетрить, что если код оставить в исходном виде, то работать будет как то не так. И возможно надо поменять `remove` на какой нибудь `.style.display = 'none'` в тоггловом варианте. Ответ указан как верный, я не понимаю, в чем проблема. Энивейс, я не вижу смысла продолжать.